# Using API in SwiftUI: Can't find error in scope

Tags: json, xcode, swiftui

I have been using Youtube to help me with learning how to use API and converting to JSON using SwiftUI. This is my first time actually using it and could use help, if possible please... this Is what my code is showing: "can not find error in scope"

This is the code so far:

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Arrabiata") else {
            
            return
        }
        
    }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data;
        error; in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }
         // Convert to JSON
        
        
    }
}
```

I am so sorry, I am still very new to this all.

Thank you!

I have tried using Youtube for help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two (actually three) serious mistakes.

- The closing brace above `let task` is wrong, it must be at the end.
- The closure of `dataTask` has **three** parameters separated by **comma**

And it's good practice to handle/print the `error`. If there is no error `data` has a value and can be forced unwrapped.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Arrabiata") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            // Convert to JSON
            // It's guaranteed that data has a value
            
        }
    }
}
```

Side note:

Rather than YouTube where *anybody* can publish *anything* read/watch serious tutorials like Hacking With Swift.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion!! I will definitely look into that! :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Arrabiata") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            // Convert to JSON
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                // Process the JSON data
                
            } catch {
                // Handle JSON parsing error
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
}
```